# Banach space with Frechet differential norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I am stuck in the following exercise. Does anyone help to to solve this problem.
Thank you for all kind help.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $S(X)$ be its unit sphere. Then the following statements are equivalent:

(a) $X$ has Frechet differential norm at $x_0$, i.e, 
$$
\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|x_0+\lambda y\|-\|x_0\|}{\lambda}
$$
uniformly exists for all $y\in S(X)$.

(b) The norm on $X$ is Frechet differential at $x_0$, i.e. there exists a continuous linear functional $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\|x_0+h\|-\|x_0\|=f(h)+0(h),
$$
where
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow}\frac{0(h)}{\|h\|}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets try $(b)\Rightarrow (a)$ here we have:

assume the norm is Frechet differentiable then:

$\|\|x_0+h\|-\|x_0\|\|=\|f(h)+0(h)\|\Rightarrow\|\frac{\|x_0+h\|-\|x_0\|}{\|h\|}\|=\|\frac{f(h)}{\|h\|}+\frac{0(h)}{\|h\|}\|$

$\Rightarrow lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\|\frac{\|x_0+h\|-\|x_0\|}{\|h\|}\|\leq lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|}+0$

But $f$ is a continuous linear functional and hence is bounded so there exists a $C\gt 0$ st $\|f(h)\|\leq C\|h\|\Rightarrow lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|}\leq lim_{h\rightarrow 0}C=C$

So it seems the limit exists, and it exists uniformly, as it does not matter which $x_0$ we take due to the boundedness of $f$

**edit** I think since we are considering the unit sphere it makes sense that $C\leq 1$